# racket: get installation checksum

Tags: git, version, racket

I know you can get your current Racket version with the [(version)](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/runtime.html?q=version#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._version%29%29) parameter:

```
Welcome to Racket v6.4.0.4.
-> (version)
"6.4.0.4"
```

Is there a simple way to get the current Racket checksum besides calling `git log | head -n 1` in your [find-collects-dir](http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/dirs.html)?

Comment: "Checksum"? Do you mean the commit number/"hash" of the revision that your current Racket installation was built on?

Comment: What I really want is a unique identifier for the current Racket installation. Git hashes work for my use-case, but I'd also like something that works for snapshot builds.

Comment: I suspect the `repo-time-stamp` collection is supposed to work for this, but it may have bitrotted for the transition to package-based Racket.